# Очистка вывода в командной строке

Tags: java, cmd

В общем, есть следующая ситуация:
Существует программа, выводящая нечто несколько раз посредством System.out.print().
Как можно очистить консоль (появляющуюся после запуска java %имя%) от вывода?
Пробовал сделать так:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process process = runtime.exec("cls");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
```

- не работает.

Также пытался таким образом:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
```

Ничего, как и в первом случае не вышло.

Comment: new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, спасибо! Работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы заработало в `Windows` вам следует запустить процесс и прикрепить текущий потоки ввода вывода к нему, тогда должно все получиться:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls")
                                      .inheritIO()
                                      .start()
                                      .waitFor();
```